# Laravel 4.2 tries to interpret Backbone.js template variables

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, laravel, laravel-4

I recently upgraded to Laravel 4.2 for a new project and created a blade view with a Backbone.js template like I am used to doing.

However, I get an exception thrown on all variables I have in my Backbone.js template because apparently Laravel 4.2 tries to interpret the Backbone.js variables.

```
<script id="UserIconTemplate" type="text/template">
    <div class="UserIcon ui-widget-content timeInterval<%= interval %>" id="<%= user.id %>">
        <div class="userBox">
        <h6><%= user.first_name %></h6>
        <img src="/img/female_user.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="buttonBarUser" data-user_id="<%= user.id %>" data-calendar_id="<%= id %>">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-help getUserNotes"></span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil editUserCalendar"></span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash removeFromCalendar"></span>
    </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

So my question is: How the hell am I supposed to work with my Backbone.js templates if:

<%=backbone_variable%> === {{$laravel_variable}}

Comment: It's weird, because nowhere in the documentation does it say that it'll also compile <%= %> tags if you didn't change the default setting. You can try setting the tags again https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php#L675 or avoid using blade all together if you're not really using blade.

Comment: Yep, it's so strange, checked the docs and I think the change logs too but it wasn't mentioned. My colleague confirmed it on his Laravel 4.2 install.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you both have asp_tags enabled in your php.ini. Changing the .ini should fix this for you: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.asp-tags

> asp_tags - Enables the use of ASP-like <% %> tags in addition to the usual  tags. This includes the variable-value printing shorthand of <%= $value %>.

So the fix is to modify your php.ini and set asp_tags=false then restart php.